# Can we use Kotlin For Loop on Android Studio EditText whose Id contains integer?

Tags: android, android-studio, for-loop, while-loop

Can we use Kotlin For Loop on EditText whose Id contains integer? I was thinking about converting the EdiText Id to sting, edit, then concatenate but I got error in the IDE.

Can we shorten this code:

```
R.id.clearNutCountButton -> {
            b1p1.text.clear()
            b2p1.text.clear()
            b3p1.text.clear()
            b1p2.text.clear()
            b2p2.text.clear()
            b3p2.text.clear()
            b1p3.text.clear()
            b2p3.text.clear()
            b3p3.text.clear()
            b1p4.text.clear()
            b2p4.text.clear()
            b3p4.text.clear()
            b1p5.text.clear()
            b2p5.text.clear()
            b3p5.text.clear()
            b1p6.text.clear()
            b2p6.text.clear()
            b3p6.text.clear()
            b1p7.text.clear()
            b2p7.text.clear()
            b3p7.text.clear()
            b1p8.text.clear()
            b2p8.text.clear()
            b3p8.text.clear()
            b1p9.text.clear()
            b2p9.text.clear()
            b3p9.text.clear()
            b1p10.text.clear()
            b2p10.text.clear()
            b3p10.text.clear()
            b1p11.text.clear()
            b2p11.text.clear()
            b3p11.text.clear()
            b1p12.text.clear()
            b2p12.text.clear()
            b3p12.text.clear()
            b1p13.text.clear()
            b2p13.text.clear()
            b3p13.text.clear()
            b1p14.text.clear()
            b2p14.text.clear()
            b3p14.text.clear()
            b1p15.text.clear()
            b2p15.text.clear()
            b3p15.text.clear()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 methods:

1 - If your EditTexts all belong to a ViewGroup let's say of id: parentGroup, you can try this (in Kotlin):

```
    parentGroup.forEach { 
        if (it is EditText) {
            it.text.clear()
        }
    }
```

2 - If they don't belong to a ViewGroup (and you don't want to group them into a group), you can do (less efficient way of writing, I won't type all of the edit texts here):

```
    listOf(b1p1, b2p1, b3p1).forEach { 
        it.text.clear()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I only learned about ViewGroup id now. It makes looping throught EditTexts faster. Follow up question: How would you write through a ViewGroup to check whether the EditTexts are blank?

Comment: The second example does not work. I used it to clear the value in certain TextViews but it got error on **clear**, Unresolved reference.

Comment: It actually depends on when in the Activity/Fragment lifecycle you are calling it. For example, let's say your EditText is in a Fragment, you should refer to it in onViewCreated() (after your views are fully created). Check out: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Lifecycle